# Mashup: Select Box / Disabled Input / Getting Info From Database

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

I am creating a form, where people can either choose a new team and then input its location or if they select a team from the list, I would like the input to be disabled - and the selected team's location to be given in the input box. This is my code so far. It doesn't work. :(

```
<select id="chooseTeam" name="chooseTeam" data-placeholder="Select Team">
    <option></option>
    {% for team in teams %}
    <option>{{team.name}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    <option>New Team</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="input_location" name="input_location"/>
```

In a separate JS File:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#chooseTeam').on('blur', function() {
        if (form.chooseTeam.value != "New Team" && form.chooseTeam.value != "Select Team") {
            $("#input_location").html("{{team.location}}");
            document.getElementById("input_location").disabled = true;
        }
    });
});
```

---

**MINI-UPDATE**

Apparently, AJAX is needed for this. I am brand new to Javascript (3 days old) so I don't know how AJAX works yet but I am at this moment googling it to try and figure it out.

---

Oh, and Merry Christmas, everybody!

"#code-on-christmas"

Comment: is that the complete javascript code, or is that wrapped in a function in an event handler?

Comment: Thanks for the tip I updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using Django and jQuery. Is that true? I cannot give you a fully detailed answer at the moment, but the code in the following line cannot work because you are mixing client-side and server-side code.

```
$("#input_location").html("{{team.location}}");
```

The expression `{{team.location}}` cannot be evaluated by Django because it only exists on the client-side in your browser. If you want Django to evaluate what has been chosen on the client-side, you should use AJAX calls between server and client by using [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Also, why don't you use jQuery selectors for all of your code? Do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#chooseTeam').on('blur', function() {
        var currentTeam = $(this).val();
        if (!$.inArray(currentTeam, ['New Team', 'Select Team'])) {
            $("#input_location").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Technically, Flask and jQuery, but there is not too much of a difference between Flask and Django in this instance. I'm actually really new to Javascript - started to learn it 3 days ago - but I will give **$.ajax()** a try

Comment: Yeah, I should use JQuery for everything - still new to JS - so sometimes I mix and mash my JS and JQuery lol.

Comment: @JoseBazBaz I'm pretty new to it as well. jQuery's documentation could be better, so I needed some time as well to get my head around it. But once it makes 'click' it's quite easy. :)

Comment: I have an idea - I think I might be able to get the same effect with just pure Flask(similar to Django in this case) and HTML

Comment: @JoseBazBaz I don't have experience with Flask, but you want to dynamically update a part of your UI without a page reload, right? In this case you need JavaScript / jQuery. But maybe I didn't exactly get what you want.

Comment: See what I am trying to do here - doesn't work yet - but that's my idea - do you think this is possible? - Because if I can do this - then I can do some hiding and showing work with a little JS to resolve my issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033262/select-soccer-team-and-output-soccer-teams-location#comment19385120_14033262

Comment: @JoseBazBaz You definitely need AJAX requests to accomplish what you want.